# Open a web application when request is made to IIS server root

Tags: iis, iis-7

Using IIS7, I have a web application (lets say it is called "MyWebApp" installed under "Default Web Site", on my web server (lets say it is called www.mywebserver.com)

What I want to achieve is that when a browser makes a request to www.mywebserver.com, I want to open MyWebApp, as if the request was www.mywebserver.com/MyWebApp.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a redirect, there are several ways to do that:

1. Add an html page with a [`meta refresh`](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)
2. Use ASP .NET Redirection methods ([Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/two-approaches-to-redirection-in-aspnet/743))
3. Use [IIS Redirect](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

I'd recommend the IIS Redirect. Follow these steps:

- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
- In Features View, double-click HTTP Redirect.
- On the HTTP Redirect page, select Redirect requests to this destination. In the corresponding box, type the file name, directory path, or URL to which you want to redirect the user.
  In the Actions pane, click Apply.

Comment: I tried this 3rd option, and I ended up in a situation in which a request to www.mywebserver.com/MyOtherApp gets redirected to www.mywebserver.com/MyWebApp/MyOtherApp.

Comment: In the HTTP Redirect window, check the "Only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)", this will not redirect `MyOtherApp`

Comment: I have to disagree Rob...I have that option checked.